# String has length multiple of three

Tags: regex

What is the regular expression for strings with length multiple of three? The {} does not work for me as it only allows a definite value for min/min-max.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should suit your needs:

```
(?:\w{3})*
```

- `\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so change it as you need
- `(?:X)` just is a *non-capturing* group
- `(?:X{3})` means *"n groups of 3 X"*

Comment: If I am looking for strings with length multiple of 3, is (?:\.*{3})* correct?

Comment: @Gannicus No, you simply need to replace the `\w` part of my answer. If you need *"any char"*, use: `(?:.{3})*`.

Comment: @phloc Haha, this one is fun, for once that `...` has a *real use* ;)