# XSD Restriction to limit element length to divisible by 4/multiple of 4

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I am writing an XSD file to lay out some rules for the structure of an XML document. One of the pieces of data held in the document is a string whose length must be divisible by 4; if it is not then the data is erroneous.

Can I write this rule into the XSD document itself, or am I resigned to validating the data afterwards?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<xsd:pattern value="^(.{4})*$"/>
```

If the field can be blank. If not, change the `*` to a `+`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I suspected there might be some regex that would work but didn't think to match groups! I am annoyed that my question was immediately downvoted and voted to close though, it is very clear what I am asking as shown by your quick response!

Comment: @Wibbler maybe your question was down voted because it doesn't show any search effort... Or it could have been close as a duplicate of [String has length multiple of three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696353/string-has-length-multiple-of-three)... Who knows ?

Comment: I'm not sure what search effort I could show, other than listing the obviously incorrect approaches (length restrictions) or completely inapplicable google results which led me to ask the question in the first place. Regardless, your answer works and I've accepted it. Hopefully it helps the next person trying to search this problem.

Comment: @Wibbler *listing the obviously incorrect approaches* will tell users that you're the kind of person that search **then** ask, instead of the ones that ask questions like *pliz do my code, I'm lazy*